# census year calculated column DAX

Tags: dax

How to adjust the below solution [source](https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Fiscal-Year-Calculated-Columns/m-p/149604)
to show census year (CY) which starts 16th of April and ends 15th of April?
(i.e.: for dates between '2020-04-16' AND '2021-04-15': 'CY2020-21', for dates between '2019-04-16' AND '2020-04-15': 'CY2019-20, and so on).

```
Financial Year =
VAR fy =
    IF (
        MONTH ( 'Dates'[Dates] ) <= 3,
        VALUE ( FORMAT ( 'Dates'[Dates], "YY" ) ) - 1,
        VALUE ( FORMAT ( 'Dates'[Dates], "YY" ) )
    )
RETURN
    CONCATENATE ( "FY", CONCATENATE ( fy, CONCATENATE ( "/", fy + 1 ) ) )
```

Comment: I have figured out a solution using SWITCH(TRUE() method (see below), but still curious if there is more elegant way of solving the question..

CenYear = 
SWITCH(TRUE(),
MONTH ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) < 4, 
YEAR ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) - 1& "-"& YEAR ( 'DateTable'[Date] ), 
MONTH ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) > 4, 
YEAR ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) &"-"& YEAR ( 'DateTable'[Date]) +1,
AND ( MONTH ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) = 4, DAY ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) < 16), 
YEAR ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) - 1& "-"& YEAR ( 'DateTable'[Date] ), 
YEAR ( 'DateTable'[Date] ) &"-"& YEAR ( 'DateTable'[Date]) +1 
)

Answer (score 0):

You can do this a bit more cleanly as follows:

```
CY = 
VAR yr = FORMAT ( STARTOFYEAR ( 'Dates'[Date], "4/15" ), "YY" )
RETURN
    "CY" & yr & "-" & yr + 1
```

---

Note: For this to work properly for the earliest year, the `Dates` table should start at the beginning of the census year.